# Trying to get this SQL query to run on phpmyadmin mysql but it doesnt work

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my query that will run in Access:

```
SELECT FMZ_FormDetActivity.*
FROM FMZ_FormDetActivity
WHERE (((FMZ_FormDetActivity.CUST_DIV)="10") AND    
    ((FMZ_FormDetActivity.ACTIVITY_DATE)>#12/31/2012#));
```

When I try to run it on phpMyAdmin it comes up with this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 5

```
SELECT FMZ_FormDetActivity . * 
FROM FMZ_FormDetActivity
WHERE (
   (
      (
           FMZ_FormDetActivity.CUST_DIV
      ) =  "10"
   )
   AND (
     (
         FMZ_FormDetActivity.ACTIVITY_DATE
      ) > #12/31/2012#));
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the semicolon and some quotes.  Also change the date string.

```
SELECT FMZ_FormDetActivity.* 
   FROM FMZ_FormDetActivity 
   WHERE  FMZ_FormDetActivity.CUST_DIV  =  10 AND  
          FMZ_FormDetActivity.ACTIVITY_DATE  > '2012-12-31' 
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and Access have drastically different syntaxes.

However, the primary cause of your error is the "LIMIT 0,30" inserted into there by phpMyAdmin after the ';' statement terminator. I'd remove that whole last part ("; LIMIT 0, 30").

Second, one thing that definitely won't work in MySQL is #12/31/2012#... Replace the "#" symbols with a single quote (') to read '12/31/2012'.

There could be other errors in that SQL statement, but try this first.

Answer (score 0):

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 5
```

This tells me instantly that you have a problem with either line #4 or line #5. Since I've used phpMyAdmin before, I know that it likes to add something similar to this `LIMIT 0 , 30` to the end of your query. If you terminate your query before this line, it wouldn't include that line with your original query. This will cause it to execute `LIMIT 0 , 30` separately, and since that is not a proper SQL statement, it wouldn't know what to do with it!

Cheers